Debian 12 - grub gets systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false by default?
I'm running Debian 12 with kernel 6.9.12-amd64.  When grub generates its config file (e.g. via grub-mkconfig), all the Debian entries have systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false appended in their Linux command.  This is not present in /etc/default/grub, where GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet" and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" (no mention of cgroups appears).  So where is this coming from?
This is a problem, because when I boot now, I get a fatal error from systemd saying

Refusing to run under cgroup v1. SYSTEMD_CGROUP_ENABLE_LEGACY_FORCE=1 not specified on kernel command line.

When I add that parameter, it boots, but I get a deprecation message and boot is delayed by 30s.
It seems like Debian is preventing using cgroups v2, but that the latest versions of systemd require it.  What should I do here?  It seems to me like I should switch to cgroups v2 and find a way to not have grub appending systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false by default, which is why I'm wondering where that's coming from.  Is there some danger or downside to enabling cgroups v2? (I also manually removed that line and booted with cgroups v2, things seem fine?)

Tried grepping for systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy in /etc/grub? Or in /etc in general?

Ah thank you @muru.  So GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false is in (and the sole contents of) /etc/default/grub.d/cgroup.cfg.  But my question remains where this file came from, why it's there, and if it's best practice to remove?  It definitely would have come in through some package updates/installations, not manually by me.  And I know that was not present when I originally did the Debian installation.  Are there any consequences for things like proprietary NVIDIA drivers, or anything else to be wary of in switching to cgroups v2?

If dpkg -S /etc/default/grub.d/cgroup.cfg reveals nothing, then grep for cgroup.cfg in /var/lib/dpkg/info

No results from either - so I will just go ahead and remove /etc/default/grub.d/cgroup.cfg, reconfigure grub, and be on my way. Thanks!
